# vtk oriented bounding box in 3d space

Tags: vtk

I have a set of data points in the 3D space and would like to fit a bounding box to them. I know that vtkOBBTree::ComputeOBB can do this for me. But I can't seem to figure out how to visualize the oriented bounding box.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For a bounding box you can use `vtkOutlineFilter`. You just have to set as input the 3D data that you want to fit. Then you create the mapper and the actor, and add it to the scene, as you would do in a typical VTK scenario. Here is a working example, in Python:

```
from vtk import *

quadric = vtkQuadric()
quadric.SetCoefficients(.5, 1, .2, 0, .1, 0, 0, .2, 0, 0)

sample = vtkSampleFunction()
sample.SetSampleDimensions(50,50,50)
sample.SetImplicitFunction(quadric)

contour = vtkContourFilter()
contour.SetInputConnection(sample.GetOutputPort())
contour.GenerateValues(5,0,1)

contourMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
contourMapper.SetInputConnection(contour.GetOutputPort())
contourMapper.SetScalarRange(0,1.2)

contourActor = vtkActor()
contourActor.SetMapper(contourMapper)

outline = vtkOutlineFilter()
outline.SetInputConnection(sample.GetOutputPort())

outlineMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
outlineMapper.SetInputConnection(outline.GetOutputPort())

outlineActor = vtkActor()
outlineActor.SetMapper(outlineMapper)
outlineActor.GetProperty().SetColor(1,1,1)

ren = vtkRenderer()
ren.SetBackground(0.188,0.373,0.647)
ren.AddActor(contourActor)
ren.AddActor(outlineActor)

renWin = vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
renWin.SetWindowName("IsoSurface")
renWin.SetSize(500,500)

iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

renWin.Render()
iren.Initialize()
iren.Start()
```